# How can I use ack (preferably ack) or grep to search for a string in a list of files?

Tags: grep, find, ack

I want to search for a string "my-search-string" in any files called search-this-one.html

In all subdirectories of my current working directory.

I want a list of full paths of the files that contain this string.  There are hundreds of files called search-this-one.html, any number of them could contain the string.

Has anyone had any success doing this.

I can get a list of files like this..

```
find . -type f -name "search-this-one.html"
```

I've tried a variety of grep and ack switches on this, all the other related answers search only for filenames that match the search string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running ack 2.x, you can use the -x option to get input from STDIN, much like xargs.

```
ack -g search-this-one.html | ack -x pattern
```

The `ack -g` says "Find any text files with names that match `search-this-one.html`", and then that's piped into `ack -x` which takes its list of input files from STDIN.

Also works for searching for filenames with regex:

```
ack -g '\.*.conf$' | ack -x searchString
```

Comment: This is a superbly quick solution. Kudos :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name "search-this-one.html" | xargs grep "my-search-string"
```

With the additional `-l` switch to `grep`, you would get a list of matching files without the exact matching position.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `-exec` in your `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name "search-this-one.html" -exec grep "my-search-string" {} \;
```

So that `find` will output a list of file names on which the command `grep "my_search_string"` will be performed.

To get the files and the occurrences in which this happens, add `-H` to the `grep`:

```
find . -type f -name "search-this-one.html" -exec grep -H "my-search-string" {} \;
```

Comment: This will search the file name.

Comment: No, this will search for these files and in all of them, `grep` to check if `my_search_string` is there or not.

Comment: Yep, it will, I forgot about that you can pass the file name to grep, I almost never use that feature. +1 for using `-exec` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: This does search the file not the filename needs the -l switch or you have to guess which file it's found in.  Good answer +1.

Comment: But @chim, didn't you want to look for the text itself? If not, it wasn't clear to me. And yes, if you add `-l` to `grep` then you are done.

Comment: I want to find which files called search-this-one.html contain "my-search-string"  Shall I amend the question to make this clearer?

Comment: @chim mmm as you like :) I just updated my answer so that it reflects both interpretations. I hope it is useful and works fine!

Comment: By the way, @chim, you can also use `-H` in your `grep` expression to print both the match and the file name. From `man grep` --> `Print the file name for each match`

Answer (score 2):

For whatever it's worth, I've never found a *succinct* way to do this using `ack`, but the following works:

```
ack --type-add foo:is:search-this-one.html --foo my-search-string
```

Explanation:

- `--type-add foo:is:search-this-one.html` : this adds (for the duration of this one command) a new type, `foo`, defined as all files whose name `is` `search-this-one.html`
- `--foo` : search only files of the type `foo`

Also, further to @fedorqui et al, you can instead use the `-exec cmd {} +` option to find, which puts all the matched filenames into the command *before* running it, eschewing the need for the `-H` flag:

```
find . -name search-this-one.html -type f -exec grep "my-search-string" {} +
```

Comment: +1 for the ack solution, I'm sure I'll be doing this again soon so will try this method out. I tried using the -x switch to pass in the lsit of files and separately one file at a time, but it didn't find all the files with the search string in.

Comment: @chim which `-x` switch?

Comment: File finding:
...........................................
  -x                            Read the list of files to search from STDIN.

Comment: You can also get the ack manual with `man ack` or, if your distro doesn't install the man pages, `ack --man`.